# setting a cookie in playwright but unable to retrieve it in application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright

#### Edit

Further fact finding, it appears that this is an issue ONLY appearing in `React v16`, but i dont know why?

not appearing in `React v18`, or `Vue v2.6.10`

---

in my playwright test im setting a cookie in the browser context like this:

```js
test.beforeEach(async ({ page, browser }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext()
  await context.addCookies([
    {
      name: AUTHTKN,
      value: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzI1NDUyMzh9.AN93Ms3qkL_mkY2_bF_-mI3MvhXVKbrsV4BRPLLF5hs',
      domain: 'localhost',
      path: '/',
      expires: moment().add(24, 'hours')
    }
  ])

  const cookies = await context.cookies()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2))

  await page.goto('/')
})
```

using console.log i can see the output

I suspect this is an issue caused by playwright which seems to automatically inject `sameSite`, but not sure since this is a representation of the cookie and I have no ability (that i know of) how I could view it in browser to be sure

```js
[
  {
    "name": "AUTHTKN",
    "value": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzI1NDUyMzh9.AN93Ms3qkL_mkY2_bF_-mI3MvhXVKbrsV4BRPLLF5hs",
    "domain": "localhost",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 7776000,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "sameSite": "Lax"
  }
]
```

in my application code, it fails to find the cookie, I load cookies from memory like this

```js
const getAll = () => {
  const pairs = document.cookie.split(';')
  const cookies = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split('=')
    cookies[(pair[0] + '').trim()] = unescape(pair.slice(1).join('='))
  }
  return cookies
}

getAll()['AUTHTKN']
// => undefined
```

within my app in real scenarios, i can set the cookie in my application goes like this, and when done this way my app can find the cookie, but mocking it within playwright is whats not seeming to work

```js
const set = (key, value, seconds, domain) => {
  // ...
  let string = `${key}=${value}`
  if (seconds) string += `; max-age=${seconds}`
  if (domain) string += `; domain=${domain}`
  string += `; path=/`
  document.cookie = string
}
const NINETYDAYSASSECONDS = 90 * 86400
cont token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzI1NDUyMzh9.AN93Ms3qkL_mkY2_bF_-mI3MvhXVKbrsV4BRPLLF5hs'
set('AUTHTKN', token, NINETYDAYSASSECONDS, null)
getAll()['AUTHTKN']
// => 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzI1NDUyMzh9.AN93Ms3qkL_mkY2_bF_-mI3MvhXVKbrsV4BRPLLF5hs'
```

I believe it has something to do with the domain as the issue or sameSite, but cant be sure

Comment: Did you ever solve this? For “I have no ability (that i know of) how I could view it in browser to be sure”, you can run the test in debug mode, have it pause/break where needed, and then inspect/open devtools and look to see if your cookie is there (where varies by browser)